# TCL Info frame not giving correct file-name and line-number?

Tags: tcl

We have a problem with `info frame` not giving the correct file-name and line-number.

We are using Tcl 8.6 with some code forked for `proc` and `source`, we are overriding `source` command with some custom code, so that some of the lines can be skipped, After this, `info frame` isn't working for this forked version.

Is there a solution for this?

Answer (score 1):

Alas, if you override bits and pieces of code like that then you lose the file tracking. It's done by tracing identities of literals and it *really* doesn't like what you're up to there.

Formally, the file tracking is known to be theoretically flaky, but it doesn't seem to be much of a problem in practice unless you get into the level of processing that you're up to. One possible workaround is to do your preprocessing by changing files into other files (e.g., in a “deploy” directory) so that `source` and `proc` can stay conventional. (Doing that sort of copy is also pretty much what you do when you build an application; you've just got a filtering copy instead of a simple one.)

## Details

The following two locations in Tcl's source contain the heart of the problem for you:

1. [`generic/tclProc.c` lines 199–280, `Tcl_ProcObjCmd()`](https://core.tcl-lang.org/tcl/file?name=generic/tclProc.c&ci=4e296652c1929fdf&ln=199,280)
2. [`generic/tclIOUtil.c`, lines 1955–1959, `TclNREvalFile()`](https://core.tcl-lang.org/tcl/file?name=generic/tclIOUtil.c&ci=4e296652c1929fdf&ln=1955,1959) (and probably [lines 1819–1823, `Tcl_FSEvalFileEx()`](https://core.tcl-lang.org/tcl/file?name=generic/tclIOUtil.c&ci=4e296652c1929fdf&ln=1819,1823) too, if you want to do file evaluation that's not `source`)

You want that code in `tclProc.c` to trigger so that the frame data is built for the procedure, but for that you need the trigger in `tclIOUtil.c` to set the triggering action. Your changes to `proc` and `source` block *both* of these. The `info frame` command reads the data that that block in `tclProc.c` generates.

Perhaps the easiest way — if you're building custom C in the first place — is to insert your processing in those two functions in `tclIOUtil.c`; I'd do it by calling a shared function that modifies the contents of the buffer in the `Tcl_Obj` passed in (which will be single-referenced at that point, and hence writable). Just… don't alter the number of newlines if you want the data out of `info frame` to be sensible.

Comment: This sort of thing is why _everywhere_ labelled `TIP #280` in the Tcl sources is scary. If it wasn't so useful to me in a few places, I'd be really annoyed about it. OK, I'm still annoyed, but I put up with the annoyance for now.